# How do get through Kolima Forest?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

I am trying to get through Kolima forest because there is apparently someone there I need to talk to. Problem is, it is a directional maze and I keep ending up back at the start, which really sucks.

How do I get through this maze? If Sveta was stil part of my party, I would use her psynergy but she left a while back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Blitz Knight Stunt's FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/960545-golden-sun-dark-dawn/faqs/61407), **you get through Kolima Forest by following your Venus Djinn guide whom you should see upon entering the forest.** To follow them, you'll need to grow some vines and such.

If you aren't seeing them when you enter the forest, you haven't used the Hermes Water on the Dream Tree in Kolima Village yet.

Hopefully that's enough detail to not spoil too much. If not, please let me know in the comments or better still revise your question to better detail the state of where you are in the game that I may provide more precise directions to guide you through this obstacle.

Comment: people i did the dream tree thing but how do you get to the kolima forest

Comment: @zackysun I don't think it's all that hard to find (so maybe you're asking the wrong question), but hopefully this is what you're looking for. Take the north exit from Kolima village and head Northwest. [Here's a map](http://www.gs-adeptsrefuge.com/dd/images/worldmap.jpg), it's #22. And [here's video of someone going to kolima forest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25klUPnNQoQ#t=9m28s). Good luck.